# Is a Fragment on the UIThread?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-runonuithread

When I first started my project, I updated the UI from all over the place. This worked for a while, because only a Seekbar was being updated from a worker thread and for some reason that worked. I then updated a TextView from the same worker thread and it crashed my app, so I started calling `runOnUIThread(new Runnable(){...});` every time I needed to update the UI from a worker thread.

My Fragments also need to update the UI and they update their own UI elements as well as the Activity elements with no errors.

Should I be using `runOnUIThread(new Runnable(){...});` in Fragments to update UI elements or are the Fragments on the UI thread?

Comment: Why you just can't use pair thread-handler? Handler helps to display all info on ui-thread. It is the simplest way. More difficult way is to use rxjava library, for example.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Handlers and read that ```runOnUIThread()``` is an easy way to update the UI.

Comment: You'll have to be familiar with this, it's the one of the fundamental things.

Comment: I looked at the developers page for Handlers and it seems like overkill for my small project. I really just want to know if code run from a Fragment is in the UI thread.

Answer (score 0):

The fragment itself as an object is not a part of the `UI`. However, the root view of the fragment is a part of this `UI`. What I mean is that the view you are returning back from the `onCreateView()` method is representing your `UI` and if you need to update any element in this view such as TextViews or Buttons from any other thread, you definitely have to use `runOnUIThread(new Runnable(){...});` method.

#### Remark

If you are using RxJava or Coroutines this operation will be much easier for you as it makes switching threads very easy.

Comment: How come a Fragment blocks the UI thread inside onViewCreated()  if it is not part of it?